# Fetch value of element by attribute using linq to xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have following xml and I want to fetch the value of node which has attribute.

```
<quiz xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="quiz.xsd">
    <mchoice>
        <question>What is the capital city of Australia?</question>
        <answer>Sydney</answer>
        <answer correct="yes">Canberra</answer>
        <answer>Melbourne</answer>
        <answer>Gold Coast</answer>
    </mchoice>
    <mchoice>
        <question>Launceston is the second largest city in which Australian state?</question>
        <answer>Victoria</answer>
        <answer>New South Wales</answer>
        <answer correct="yes">Tasmania</answer>
        <answer>Western Australia</answer>
    </mchoice>
</quiz>


public class Question
{
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public List<string> Answers { get; set; }
    public string CorrectAnswer { get; set; }

}
```

I tried following query but I am getting null in **CorrectAnswer** filed

```
var questions = from docs in _doc.Descendants("mchoice")
                        let answers = _doc.Elements("answer")
                        select new Question
                        {
                            QuestionText = docs.Element("question").Value,
                            Answers = docs.Elements("answer").Select(a => a.Value).ToList(),
                            CorrectAnswer=docs.Elements("answer").Where(x=>x.Attribute("correct").Value=="yes").Select(x=>x)
```

**Excepted Output**

- QuestionText-What is the capital city of Australia?
- Answer-List
- CorrectAnswer-Canberra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
CorrectAnswer=docs.Elements("answer").Where(x=>x.Attribute("correct").Value=="yes").Select(x=>x)
```

To be:

```
CorrectAnswer=docs.Elements("answer")
   .First(x=> x.HasAttributes && x.Attribute("correct").Value=="yes")
   .Value
```

Comment: Just one question.Why you apply First extension method?

Comment: Because your Where().Select() returns a list and you want just the value.  Actually should put `.Value` after the First(), I'll edit answer, since you probably just want the text and not the element.